# Mobile website layout doesn't appear in portrait mode in tablets

Tags: bug, mobile-web

I have two Android tablets, and I notice that the Stack Overflow website doesn't appears in mobile website mode, even in portrait mode. It continues to appear like the desktop site, even though I haven't selected the desktop site option in my browser.

[image: Screenshot]

This makes the website inconvenient for touch devices. I guess, Stack Overflow should increase the maximum screen width limit for their mobile website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you can force Stack Overflow to display its mobile view.

1. Scroll down to the bottom of the page.
2. Click the *Mobile* link (will trigger `StackExchange.switchMobile("on")`).

**Screenshot for reference**

[image: Screenshot of Stack Overflow footer, with link to Mobile highlighted]

Comment: But it should automatically do that, right?